# jQuery form not submitting on timeout - e[h] is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

This question has been asked before on SO but no success, perhaps a different scenario

Here is my form

```
<form id="testSubmit" method="post" action="submit.php">
     <!--The value of following field will be obtained when user submits test or time runs out -->
     <input type="hidden" name="user_answer" id="user_answer" value=""/>
     <input type="submit" id="submit" style="padding:5px;" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Here is my Javascript and jQuery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function()
    {
   //pick up the options selected by the student and populate #userAnswer
        $('#testSubmit').submit(function()
        {
            var string='';
            $('.question').each(function () 
            {
                string += $(this).find('input[type="radio"]:checked').length ? $(this).find('input:checked').val() : 'z';
            });
            $('#user_answer').val(string);
        });

//timer for countdown and to submit the form
        var delay=5;
        function countdown()
        {
            setTimeout(countdown,1000);
            $('#timer').html("Time"+delay);
            delay--;
            if(delay<0)
            {
                $("#testSubmit").submit();
                delay=0;

            }
        }
    countdown();
    });
    </script>
```

But this doesn't submit and gives error `e[h] is not a function`;

I also tried `document.getElementById("testSubmit").submit()` and it gives error `document.getElementById("testSubmit").submit() is not a function`.

Same error with `document.forms[0].submit`

**EDIT**

I put an `alert('Hello');` inside timer and it works .So the timer is working fine.The problem is as soon as the time reaches zero,the error shows up.

Comment: Try to declare delay var outside of the  $('document').ready, probably its not getting it as a global var. Have you tried to pull out the setTimeOut? Just to test (try to declare your set timeout outside of the function, or do a: if var timeout == false {timeout = settimeout...}?

Comment: @sagits: I put an `alert('Hello');` there and it works .So the timer is working fine.The problem is as soon as the time reaches zero,the error shows up.

Comment: When you are doing document.getElementById("#testSubmit").submit() remove the #

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**"But this doesn't submit and gives error e[h] is not a function;"**

change id="submit" to something else. The reason is that if you have an input element with id of submit, it will set a submit property to the form with the HTMLInputElement. So you could not call the .submit method on the HTMLFormElement.

Comment: @A Paul:You know what? It worked!!! Thanks for this great information.Will take care next time

Comment: Once again I was a split second late. Nice answer ;) +1

Comment: +1 to both of you, for explaining the issue and correcting other possible looping issue. :)

Comment: @APaul:There is a slight problem.Now the forms submits directly without populating the `#user_answer`.So when I `var_dump($_POST['user_answer'])` on nest page I get a null string

Comment: move your "$('#testSubmit').submit(function()" code in a common function and then call it instead of $("#testSubmit").submit();

Comment: or instead of $("#testSubmit").submit(); try $("#testSubmit").trigger( "submit" )

Comment: @APaul:I tried last one and it worked thanks.Accepted .MISSION COMPLETED.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your submit button id to something else than "submit". For example "submitButton".

```
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" style="padding:5px;" value="Submit"/>
```

Also this change should prevent unnecessary JS code execution:

```
function countdown() {
        if (delay < 0) {
            $("#testSubmit").submit();
            delay = 0;
        } else {
            setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
            $('#timer').html("Time " + delay);
            delay--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: :There is a slight problem.Now the form submits directly without populating the #user_answer.So when I var_dump($_POST['user_answer']) on next page I get an empty string

Comment: Sorry but that's a different problem.